# Eclipse built-in jar export option vs Maven assembly plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, jar

I use IntelliJ IDEA to generate a jar file with `maven-assembly-plugin`.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>test.LeanFTest</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-fatjar-${project.version}</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It didn't work, it asks continuously for dependencies during execution. I was unable to use jar file, so I imported the project to Eclipse and used the built-in jar export option. This jar is working fine. I couldn't find what the difference is between these jar files.

Comment: What error do you get when you try to run your jar?

Comment: @y.bedrov : I get error message about missing dependencies.

Comment: You need to post the error message verbatim in the question itself. Also, can you create an [MCVE](https://politics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment)? This will help us to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @defaultlocale : There isn't any exact error message, it just ask for dependencies continuously.

Comment: @plaidshirt Ah, that's more complicated, I see. Please, add this explanation to the question itself. You can also provide a [redacted] maven output to demonstrate what exactly happens.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is probably that Eclipse is generating a "Class-Path:" entry in the manifest file.
Try to update the assembly conf in your .pom file by adding something like (by heart, not checked):

```
<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
```

Answer (score 1):

By default the maven-assembly-plugin will not bundle all the dependencies required for your own jar to run standalone.

So you will need to add this below under the plugin configuration:

```
<descriptorRefs>
    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
</descriptorRefs>
```

As a result, the plugin tag becomes:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>make-assembly</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>test.LeanFTest</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-fatjar-${project.version}</finalName>
        <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef> <!-- the secret -->
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You can run:

```
java -jar path/to/LeanFTest.jar
```

To directly run the program.